# Can I set a lag time in between touchesBegan in Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

My app has multiple balls, but only can be moved at a time. My code below shows that at **touchesBegan** I set specific fields used in **touchesMoved**. Within **touchesCancelled** and **touchesEnded** I reset everything.

This is my first Swift app, but not my first program, I know users like to try and crash apps.  So with two fingers I started touching multiple balls as fast as I could, and eventually, yes, I ran through touchesBegan on another ball before the first one could be set as the "moving" ball.
Is there any lag property where I can make the iOS wait even 0.3 seconds between touchesBegan?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    let touchedNodes = self.nodes(at: location)
    for node in  touchedNodes{
        if let theNode = node as? MyBall {
            if theNode.nodeType == .ball, theNode.isMoving == false,
                (myGV.currentBall == nil) {
                    theNode.isMoving = true
                    theNode.zPosition += 1
                    myGV.currentBall = theNode
                }
            }
        }
      }

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
    guard touches.first != nil else { return }
    if let touch = touches.first, let node = myGV.currentBall, node.isMoving == true {
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        node.position = touchLocation
        node.isMoving = true
        node.inSlot = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want o disable all touches for 0.3s?

Comment: @StefanOvomate No, just the begans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the natural thing is organize it around one individual active touch.  In `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded`, and `touchesCancelled`, ignore everything when there's no active touch, and ignore any touches that are not the active touch.  In `touchesBegan`, ignore new touches if there's already an active touch.  Finally, in `touchesBegan`, if there's no active touch and the touch is on a ball, that touch becomes the active one and that ball becomes the being-moved ball.  Sketch:

```swift
// activeTouch is a UITouch?

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  for touch in touches {
    if activeTouch == nil {
      // Look for a touched ball; if found set that as the moving ball
      // and set this touch as activeTouch
    }
  }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
  guard let active = activeTouch else { return }
  for touch in touches {
    if touch == active {
      // Do stuff with the moving ball
    }
  }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
  guard let active = activeTouch else { return }
  for touch in touches {
    if touch == active {
      // The moving ball stops moving, reset activeTouch to nil
    }
  }
}

// Probably touchesCancelled should be the same as touchesEnded, or
// maybe you'd want to move the ball back to the starting position;
// depends on your game.
```

Comment: I thought I WAS doing that. Thanks to your simplified template I found where I was messing up.  Thank you